# How to use images from Azure Functions Blob Trigger with Form Recognizer

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use Azure Functions to wrap an application using Form-Recognizer written in Python. My issue is getting a JPEG using the BlobTrigger into a format that the Form-Recognizer can work with.

The basic code for opening the image is

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO 
import azure.functions as func

def main(blobin: func.InputStream, blobout: func.Out[bytes], context: func.Context):
image = Image.open(blobin)
```

The image has class class: 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'.

The code for calling the Form-Recognizer analyze is as follows:

```py
base_url = r"<url>" + "/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom"
model_id = "<model-id>"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
     'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<subscription-key>',
}
resp = None
try:
    url = base_url + "/models/" + model_id + "/analyze" 
    resp = http_post(url = url, data = image, headers = headers)
    print("Response status code: %d" % resp.status_code)    
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Unfortunately, the data = image in the http_post needs to be class: 'bytes'.

So, I tried various ways using PIL to convert the input image to a byte format.

My two main approaches were

```py
with BytesIO() as output:
    with Image.open(input_image) as img:
    img.save(output, 'JPEG')
    image = output.getvalue()
```

and

```py
image = Image.open(input_image)
imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
image.save(imgByteArr, format='JPEG')
imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
```

Both of these approaches give me a byte format, however, it still doesn't work. Either way, I end up with this response:

```
{'error': {'code': '2018', 'innerError': {'requestId': '8cff8e76-c11a-4893-8b5d-33d11f7e7646'}, 'message': 'Content parsing error.'}}
```

Does anyone know the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code [`blob.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/blob/dev/azure/functions/blob.py) for the class `func.InputStream` from GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-functions-python-library`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library), you can directly get the image bytes from the `blobin` variable of `func.InputStream` class via its `read` function, as the figure below.

[image]

Meanwhile, refer to the document [`Form Recognizer API`](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel), the `Content-Type` header should be `multipart/form-data`.

So I changed the offical sample code to use in Azure Function as below.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
import azure.functions as func

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'keys': '{string}',
})

def main(blobin: func.InputStream):
    body = blobin.read()
    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
        conn.request("POST", "/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{id}/analyze?%s" % params, body, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        print(data)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Please don't use any Python 2 functions in Azure Functions which only support Python 3.6.

Comment: Although, my issue is not related to `images` but, `body = blobin.read()` this works like charm